# Reading lines backwards relative to a line in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am looping over all lines one by one using

```
line = file.readline()
```

Every line is now searched for a particular string(XYZ) -

```
line.startswith('XYZ')
```

I am not able to figure out how to get to couple of lines behind relative to the line where match was found for the string `XYZ`.

I understand that this could be something trivial but couldn't make it.

Comment: It's not trivial. Filesystems are not designed to read files backwards.

Comment: related: [Get last n lines of a file with Python, similar to tail](http://stackoverflow.com/q/136168/4279)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`collections.deque()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) to cache previous 2 lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from collections import deque

cached_lines = deque(maxlen=2) # keep 2 lines
for line in sys.stdin:
    if line.startswith('XYZ'):
        sys.stdout.writelines(cached_lines)
    cached_lines.append(line)
```

The advantage is that you don't need to read the whole file into memory.

#### Example

```
$ python . <input >output
```

#### Input

```
XYZ 1
2
3
4
XYZ 5
XYZ 6
7
8
9
XYZ 10
11
12
```

#### Output

```
3
4
4
XYZ 5
8
9
```

Answer (score 0):

file.tell() gives current file pointer. And file.seek(pointer) sets the file pointer to given pointer. Like below code,

pointer = file.tell()

..

..

..

file.seek(pointer)

Answer (score 0):

You need to save all readed lines or simply use `readlines` method.

```
lines = file.readlines()
for i in range(0, len(lines)): 
    if lines[i].startswith("XYZ"):
        print lines[i-2]
        print lines[i-1]
```