# How to create a finite length generator from an infinite generator

Tags: javascript, typescript, yield, iterable

So I have a javascript generator (below) which continues to yield random numbers ad infinitum.

```
function* createRandomNumberStream(): IterableIterator<number> {
  while (true) {
    yield Math.random()
  }
}
```

How can I write a generator function with the type `(it: Iterable<T>, n: number) => Iterable<T>`, where it returns a new iterable which ends after n yields?

Note the `createRandomStream()` generator isn't really relevant, it's just an example of an unending iterable generator. I'm trying to make a generator which basically slices an iterable.

Comment: I believe you need [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to slice a generator object or iterator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732311/how-to-slice-a-generator-object-or-iterator-in-python)

Comment: @Hamms apologies for the confusion, this is a javascript/typescript question, not python.

Comment: oh, my apologies

Comment: [Some good usable examples](https://github.com/vitaly-t/prime-lib/blob/main/src/utils.ts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
function* createRandomNumberStream() {
    while (true) {
        yield Math.random()
    }
}

function* take<T>(it: Iterator<T>, count: number) {
    let currentCount = 0
    while (currentCount++ < count) {
        yield it.next().value
    }
}

const stream = take(createRandomNumberStream(), 3)

for (const num of stream) {
    console.log(num)
}
```