# Dynamic generator unpacking

Tags: python, generator

Is there any way to write

```
a, b = generator
a, b, c = generator
```

and so on, meaning that the generator somehow would know how long exactly it should generate new items without presetting generator length (e.g. it is potentially infinite generator)?

Comment: You could *tell* the generator how many items you'll want when you create it.  Or it could be one that can create an infinite number of values.  Since you've provided *no* information about the generator, you  want, not much interesting to say.

Comment: Use `a, b, c = itertools.islice(generator, 3)` - see [How to slice a generator object or iterator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732311/how-to-slice-a-generator-object-or-iterator-in-python)

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your replies, but my question was about how to do it without setting actual count of upacking values. I've edited my question for more clarity.

Comment: @razgibator that sounds like it could be functionality that requires modification of the interpreter

Comment: @C.Nivs I start to think so, just asked if there was some non-obvious way to solve, since in python there are a lot of magic tricks

Comment: No, unpacking does not support this.

Comment: @razgibator ALTERNATIVE - SOLUTUION. Actually, is not exactly the same question. I have write a solution for you problem in the following post (Search by my name): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732311/how-to-slice-a-generator-object-or-iterator/60607125#60607125