# How to paginate an aggregation pipeline result in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a web app where I store some data in Mongo, and I need to return a paginated response from a find or an aggregation pipeline. I use Django Rest Framework and its pagination, which in the end just slices the [Cursor](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor) object. This works seamlessly for Cursors, but aggregation returns a [CommandCursor](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/command_cursor.html#pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor), which does not implement `__getitem__()`.

```py
cursor = collection.find({})
cursor[10:20] # works, no problem

command_cursor = collection.aggregate([{'$match': {}}])
command_cursor[10:20] # throws not subscriptable error
```

What is the reason behind this? Does anybody have an implementation for `CommandCursor.__getitem__()`? Is it feasible at all?

I would like to find a way to not fetch all the values when I need just a page. Converting to a list and then slicing it is not feasible for large (100k+ docs) pipeline results. There is a workaround with based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34732818/1900672), but this only works for the first few pages, and the performance drops rapidly for pages at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongo has certain aggregation pipeline stages to deal with this, like [$skip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) and [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) that you can use like so:

```
aggregation_results = list(collection.aggregate([{'$match': {}}, {'$skip':  10}, {'$limit':  10}]))
```

Specifically as you noticed Pymongo's `command_cursor` does not have implementation for `__getitem__` hence the regular iterator syntax does not work as expected. I would personally recommend not to tamper with their code unless you're interested in becoming a contributer to their package.

Answer (score 2):

The MongoDB cursor for `find` and `aggregate` functions in a different way since cursor result from aggregation query is a result of precessed data (in most cases) which is not the case for find-cursors as they are static and hence documents can be skipped and limitted to your will.

You can add the paginator limits as `$skip` and `$limit` stages in the aggregation pipeline.

For Example:

```
command_cursor = collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            # Match Conditions
        }
    },
    {
        "$skip": 10  # No. of documents to skip (Should be `0` for Page - 1)
    },
    {
        "$limit": 10  # No. of documents to be displayed on your webpage
    }
])
```