# If/ Else in python

Tags: python, html, csv

I want to read the last 24 rows of a csv file using python. So for example if the csv Data has 500 rows, I want to write row 476 to row 500. I dont know how many rows the csv file has. I tried this code, doesn't work. 
Can someone help me?

```
z=0 
r=0

for row in csvData:  
    z += 1      

for row in csvData:  

    if r > (z-30) || r < z:    
        html.write('{ x: new Date('+ row[0] + '), y:' + row[2] + '},')   
    r += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your code doesn't work is that `csvData` has been read completely in the first `for` loop.

You'd need to "rewind" the file with `csvData.seek(0)` between the two loops. See ["Why can't I call read() twice on an open file?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file)

There's a shorter way though, you could load all the lines as a list with `readlines()`, and select the last 24 lines directly:

```
for row in csvData.readlines()[-24:]:
    # do something with row
```

This should work fine as long as your `csvData` isn't huge.

If you need a more efficient (but longer) method, you could use the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7047765/6419007) to ["Get last n lines of a file with Python, similar to tail"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136168/get-last-n-lines-of-a-file-with-python-similar-to-tail).

Comment: I tried this and it does not work:                  csvData.readlines()[-24:]
    html.write('{ x: new Date('+ row[0] + '), y:' + row[2] + '},')